# MS excel Cells Matching

Tags: excel, matching, cells

I have a column with cells which has 2 details like in this form: IMEI 1 / IMEI 2 (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxaxdcxx), separated by /.

I have another cell with single details : IMEI 1 (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx).

How to check if this IMEI 1 exists in the column of cells having both IMEI1/IMEI2.

VLOOKUP does not help ( both exact or approximate match), provide any solution please.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing *where* it is, `countif` will do like

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"*"&B1&"*")
```

It will be 0 if nothing is there and a number >0 shows how many times it is in the range.

Still, I assume, you need to know at which row it is. In that case something like this will do:

```
=MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(B1,A:A)),ROW(A:A)))
```

> This is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>.